# Необязательный параметр scanf

Tags: c

Хочу сделать в программу интерфейс. Чтобы писали например "push 982" и в массив попадало 982. Но также хочу реализовать команды: pop и break. Но считывание в бесконечном цикле я произвожу таким образом:

```
scanf("%s %d", &cmd, &num);
```

cmd - сама команда, num - число. И из-за этого формата человеку приходится писать "pop 0" или "break 0". Так как формат введёный в scanf требует пробел и число, иначе не воспринимает. 
Можно ли как-нибудь сделать ,чтобы num - был необязательным и чтобы если пишешь слово без числа, оно всё равно бы считывалось? 
Или это реализовывать можно только посимвольным считыванием? (тогда это не стоит того)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", &cmd);
if (!strcmp(cmd, "push")
{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    ...
}
else
{...}
```

не канает?

Comment: В этом случаи нужно писать слово, нажимать enter и писать число - это не удобно

Comment: нет, не нужно, scanf до пробела прочтет как строку, проигнорировав остаток в stdin

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо огромное, а я думал enter нажимать, оказывает попробельно, завтра опущу одногруппника))

Comment: После работы с push число пропишите fflush(stdin) - вычистим к чертям stdin. Попробуйте.
Ну и можете код скинуть, возможно логика программы не совсем верна

Comment: Всё уже работает, ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: обращайтесь.

Comment: И все же в подобных случаях проще (и надежней) читать целыми строками

    while (fgets(str, strsize, stdin)) {
      ...

а потом проверять результат `sscanf` (количество успешно введенных в соответствии с форматом аргументов)

    switch (sscanf(str, "%s %d", str, &num)) {
    case 2:
       ... ;
    case 1:
       .... break;
    default:
       error();
    }

как-то так.

Comment: @avp, Спасибо, учту! Но switch не работает со строками :( Придётся делать if.

Comment: @iproger, а при чем здесь

    Но switch не работает со строками

???

`sscanf()` (так же, как и `scanf`) возвращает **int**.

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет "Подавление ввода".
Если коротко, то поставьте звездочку между процентом и спецификатором формата, это заставит scanf считать, но никуда не присваивать.

```
scanf("%*s %d", &int_num);
```

Comment: А как мне узнать какую команду ввёл пользователь?

Comment: Тогда парсите ввод.